# How to append tooltip above all elements including body?

Tags: css, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, tooltip

I am using kendo grid where one of the td has tooltip but for the first row my tooltip is hiding under the kendo header, Any idea how to resolve this issue i tried to make it work with tooltip-append-to-body and also tried to target with css but its not working.

config.js

```
{
    field: 'locationComments',
    title: 'Location Comments',
    width: '210px',
    filterable: false,
    sortable: false,
    template: function () {
    return '<textarea class="zIndexTooltip" '+
    'data-tooltip-html-unsafe="<div>{{512 - this.dataItem.locationComments.length}} characters left</div>" '+
    'tooltip-trigger="{{{true: \'focus\', false: \'never\'}[this.dataItem.locationComments.length >= 0 || this.dataItem.locationComments.length == null ]}}" '+
    'tooltip-placement="top" tooltip-append-to-body="true" tooltip-class = "bluefill" '+
    'maxlength="512" #=gridStatus=="NOT_EDITABLE" ? "disabled" : "" # type="text" id="locationComments" name="locationComments" ng-model="this.dataItem.locationComments" ></textarea>';
}
```

config.css

```
.k-grid tr td textarea.zIndexTooltip {
    z-index:100020;
}
```

Comment: Did you try setting a lower z-index on the overlapping element? Also if it is absolutely positionned you probably need to set it on the parent too

Answer (score 0):

I added below code in my config and set the z-index using .tooltip that solves my problem.

$tooltipProvider.options({ 
      appendToBody: true 
    });